# Can't run date difference in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_paid date NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_due date NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', '2019-05-03', '2019-05-02'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2019-06-03', '2019-06-02'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-02'), 
       ('LMUS02', '2019-05-03', '2019-05-07'), 
       ('LMUS02', '2019-06-07', '2019-06-07')
```

I tried to run this query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM the_debt_paid - the_debt_due) AS date_diff 
FROM my_table
```

And give me this error:

```
ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM the_debt_paid - the_debt_due) AS dat...
```

I'm kind of stuck in this query and why the EXTRACT function doesn't work, could you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `extract()`, a simple diff will do.

```
SELECT the_debt_paid - the_debt_due AS date_diff 
FROM my_table
```

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) the difference between two `date` values is the number of days between them.

Extract works on `date`, `timestamp` and `interval` expressions. As the manual states, the difference between two `date` values is an `integer`, and `extract` simply doesn't work on integers.

Additionally, `extract(day from some_interval)` only gives you the day part of the interval, **not** the length of the interval in days. E.g. for an interval value of `3 months 0 days`, `extract(day from ...)` would return `0`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @a_horse_with_no_name. Please, do you know why the function EXTRACT doesn't work? I tried this example `SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')-TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))`and it returns the difference as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your edit @a_horse_with_no_name, that's the reason why even when `the_debt_paid` and `the_debt_due` are dates the query doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (DATE_PART('year', '2012-01-01'::date) - DATE_PART('year', '2011-10-02'::date)) * 12 +
              (DATE_PART('month', '2012-01-01'::date) - DATE_PART('month', '2011-10-02'::date));
```

-- Result: 3
here is an example u can try this out

Comment: Hello @sas21, thank you for the response. Does your code work in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Perhaps if you put your answer formatted as code you won't have a downvote (use three backticks, then your code, then three backticks). Anyway, you are kind by sharing your knowledge.